# Accepting Multiple Answers

Tags: support

It is not possible to accept more than one answer to any question but what if two people give a perfect answer each in their own way? How do we appreciate their response?

Comment: See related discussions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180977/accepting-an-answer-when-multiple-correct-answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upvote both and pick one that was better somehow (better written, explained better, better formatted, etc) and accept that.

Comment: That may seem like an obvious thing to do but what if two answers were equal appropriate and I want both the anwerers to get appreciation for answering?

Comment: @iluvt: If either of them are mine, then pick that one.  Otherwise you arbitrarily pick one, although no two answers are ever truly equal.  Flip a coin if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Nice one, Olin! Pretty useful. See I picked your answer.